# How to rename scheduler job Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I would like rename scheduler job in Oracle, is it possible?

```
dba_scheduler_jobs(owner = "db", name = "my_job")
=> dba_scheduler_jobs(owner = "db", name = "my_own_job");
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 10):

A job is a database object, so the RENAME command works natively

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'MY_BAD_NAME',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'begin null; end;',
  6      start_date      => systimestamp,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
  8      enabled         => true);
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> rename MY_BAD_NAME to BETTER_NAME;

Table renamed.


SQL> select job_name from user_scheduler_jobs;

JOB_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BETTER_NAME
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for answer, but it doesn't work.
I'm using pl/sql developer and of course I use the schema too.
and when I try: 
alter object my_schema.my_job rename to my_own_job; 
it finish with error.

Comment: why did you run 'alter ... rename?' Connor showed just do 'rename old_job to new_job'

Comment: This is a neat trick, but is this syntax supported?  The [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/RENAME.html#GUID-573347CE-3EB8-42E5-B4D5-EF71CA06FAFC) says "Use the RENAME statement to rename a table, view, sequence, or private synonym."

Comment: I'll file a doc bug for that. Thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rename, you can create/replicate job and drop the old one.

Below, my_new_job1 has created.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name          =>  'my_new_job1',
   program_name      =>  'my_saved_program', 
   repeat_interval   =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=12',
   comments          =>  'Daily at noon');
END;
/
```

Below, my_new_job2 has created with same details as my_new_job1

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name          =>  'my_new_job2',
   program_name      =>  'my_saved_program', 
   repeat_interval   =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=12',
   comments          =>  'Daily at noon');
END;
/
```

Below an old job my_new_job1 has been deleted.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB ('my_new_job1');
END;
/
```